# JavaScript to disable Javascript

Tags: javascript

After some security concerns about user plugins running spyware, I'm looking for a way to disable all JavaScript before and after my site's JS. Ideas?

Is there a way to unset all native JavaScript, or block plugins from modifying a site's code with JavaScript? This is a huge security threat and I'm hoping it's easily remedied.

EDIT: I'm referring to browser add-ons. Basically, any JavaScript code that I didn't write myself and put on my site.

Comment: Do you mean browser plugins or what? What would you classify as the "site's JS"? Your problem description is a bit vague. The better you describe your problem, the more likely it is that you get useful answers. From what I understand now, the answer would be "no".

Comment: So, you want to include code on your page, that "disables" plugins in the user's browser? That's certainly not possible.

Comment: It's not possible. However I wonder how's that a reason to downvote the post. I'd be curious what is the maximum of what I can disable by javascript.

Comment: If you are concerned about [cross–site scripting attacks (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), you can't prevent them entirely but there are measures to reduce vulnerability. Some libraries or frameworks are intended to help, but none are guaranteed to be 100% effective. You likely need to find a security specialist to advise for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to unset all native JavaScript, or block plugins from modifying a site's code with JavaScript?

No.

> This is a huge security threat and I'm hoping it's easily remedied.

It is, yes: get your users to stop installing spyware.

Look, even if the spyware isn’t able to use an add-on to modify your site, there are any number of other possibilities for mucking about at a level above the browser. You can’t fix a fundamentally unsafe computer from the web side.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found that was effective against the spyware in question was putting some garbage JavaScript below the JavaScript on my site. Here's an example:

```
(function() {
    ....
});

thisIsGibberish
```

This sort of solution can be countered easily with placing a semi-colon in front of any code, but this was the kind of thinking I was trying to inspire.